# AutocompleteTextView + android:inputType="textMultiLines" --> Crash

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-inputtype

I wanted my ACTV to be able to display  text over more than one line because the dropdown items are quite long strings.

SingleLine=false did not work but i read the correct way was **textMultiLine**. I tried it and it crashed. Anyone knows about this ?

I could *see* why having more than one line might cause an out of bound exception (typically trying to reach the line 2 when it has not been displayed yet or something) but the real understanding is beyond me.

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/actvSearchStuff"
        style="@style/MyEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/start_search_stuff"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" 
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

Without this I have a perfectly working autocomplete, with or without a custom layout to display the dropdown.

The (beginning of the)crash log :

```
    10-13 18:24:41.641: E/InputEventReceiver(21110): Exception dispatching input event.
    10-13 18:24:41.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:584)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:578)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.text.Layout.getOffsetAtStartOf(Layout.java:1280)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.text.Layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(Layout.java:1101)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.widget.TextView.getOffsetAtCoordinate(TextView.java:10562)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.widget.TextView.getOffsetForPosition(TextView.java:10538)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:5548)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.widget.Editor.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:1264)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:9217)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8132)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2113)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2113)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2113)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
    10-13 18:24:41.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21110):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2113)
```

Another part of it :

```
10-13 18:24:41.671: E/AndroidRuntime(21110): Process: com.ier.tepv.base, PID: 21110
10-13 18:24:41.671: E/AndroidRuntime(21110): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1
10-13 18:24:41.671: E/AndroidRuntime(21110):    at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:584)
10-13 18:24:41.671: E/AndroidRuntime(21110):    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:578)
10-13 18:24:41.671: E/AndroidRuntime(21110):    at android.text.Layout.getOffsetAtStartOf(Layout.java:1280)
10-13 18:24:41.671: E/AndroidRuntime(21110):    at android.text.Layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(Layout.java:1101)
10-13 18:24:41.671: E/AndroidRuntime(21110):    at android.widget.TextView.getOffsetAtCoordinate(TextView.java:10562)
10-13 18:24:41.671: E/AndroidRuntime(21110):    at android.widget.TextView.getOffsetForPosition(TextView.java:10538)
10-13 18:24:41.671: E/AndroidRuntime(21110):    at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:5548)
10-13 18:24:41.671: E/AndroidRuntime(21110):    at android.widget.Editor.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:1264)
```

Comment: Means you want to show text in more than one line after selecting the dropdown item?

Comment: yes. The hint takes only few words but the selected String is far longer (this is why I later added a custom layout for the dropdow display).

Comment: Yes this is because of custom layout of dropdown, you should post custome layout code also.

Comment: No it is not, imo, because this crash happens "with or without a custom layout to display the dropdown"

Comment: I have created an app for checking the issue, it working fine hare. I have checked it with ArrayAdapter as well as SimpleCursorAdapter, everything is Ok.

Comment: Ill create a dummy project to check

Comment: Ok, i did it and it works indeed. So it is not the autocomplete but just something blocking my view expansion. My bad, always do a dummy project to test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63104/discussion-between-ashish-tiwari-and-poutrathor).